# Add items to ListBox on page load and transfer an item to another ListBox on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

'This Code is not working. Please Help.
'Not sure what is needed to do here.

```
Public Class WebForm2
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ListBox1.Items.Add("test")
    ListBox1.Items.Add("test2")
End Sub

Protected Sub AddOneButton0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddOneButton0.Click
    If (ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
        MsgBox("please select an item")
    Else
        ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem)
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

'Adding HTML to help figure out if i did anything wrong with my code.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="GBATExcel.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 904px">

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox1" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 101px; left: 28px; height: 170px; width: 111px;"></asp:ListBox>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  
&nbsp;

        <br />

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox2" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 103px; left: 223px; height: 167px; width: 131px;"></asp:ListBox>
        <asp:Button ID="RemoveAllButton" runat="server" Text="&lt;&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 435px; left: 153px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="AddOneButton2" runat="server" Text="&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 308px; left: 157px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="RemoveOneButton2" runat="server" Text="&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 565px; left: 156px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="AddAllButton" runat="server" Text="&gt;&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 194px; left: 153px;"/>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox3" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 302px; left: 29px; height: 177px; width: 106px;"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox4" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 520px; left: 223px; height: 170px; width: 129px;"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:Button ID="AddOneButton0" runat="server" Text="&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 110px; left: 157px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="RemoveOneButton0" runat="server" Text="&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 151px; left: 158px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="RemoveAllButton0" runat="server" Text="&lt;&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 233px; left: 154px;"/>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox5" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 730px; left: 28px; height: 170px; width: 111px;"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox6" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 302px; left: 223px; height: 171px; width: 128px;"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:Button ID="AddOneButton3" runat="server" Text="&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 737px; left: 156px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="RemoveOneButton3" runat="server" Text="&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 350px; left: 157px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="AddAllButton1" runat="server" Text="&gt;&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 396px; left: 153px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="RemoveAllButton1" runat="server" Text="&lt;&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 648px; left: 152px;"/>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox7" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 520px; left: 29px; height: 170px; width: 110px;"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBox8" runat="server" style="position:absolute; top: 729px; left: 222px; height: 170px; width: 134px;"></asp:ListBox>

        <asp:Button ID="AddOneButton4" runat="server" Text="&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 525px; left: 156px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="RemoveOneButton4" runat="server" Text="&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 776px; left: 156px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="AddAllButton2" runat="server" Text="&gt;&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 607px; left: 152px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="AddAllButton0" runat="server" Text="&gt;&gt;" style="position:absolute; top: 819px; left: 152px;"/>

        <asp:Button ID="RemoveAllButton2" runat="server" Text="&lt;&lt;" style="position:absolute; top: 864px; left: 152px;"/>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
</asp:Content>
```

'Basically i am having trouble with this and wanted some help

Comment: `Page_Load` looks fine but  don't understand what you want to do with the `Button0_Click`

Comment: I want to add one item call it "test" to another listbox. and then remove that item from the first listbox.

Comment: By buttonClick to listbox2 you mean?

Comment: yes! thats correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the items inside a `Not IsPostBack` condition:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add("test")
        ListBox1.Items.Add("test2")
    End If
End Sub
```

And remove the item from `ListBox1` before adding it to `ListBox2`:

```
Protected Sub AddOneButton0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddOneButton0.Click
    If (ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
        MsgBox("please select an item")
    Else
        Dim item As ListItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
        ListBox2.Items.SelectedIndex = -1
        ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: the selected item must be reset before inserting the new item in ListBox2

Comment: this is giving me an error saying the item was deleted first but i want the item to add to listbox 2 and then delete from listbox1.

Comment: now when i click the add button with selected item being "test" it is adding a test2 item twice. not sure why. Added HTML code above.

Comment: In `Page_Load`, you can try putting the code inside `If Not IsPostBack`.

Comment: You're the Best! Same thing to remove an item from a list box 2 right with another button?

Comment: Yes. You only need to do it once. The ViewState will maintain the change across postbacks.

Comment: would adding everything in a listbox to another with a click of a button would this code work? 

`Protected Sub AddAllButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddAllButton.Click
        For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
            ListBox2.Items.Add(ListBox1.Items(i).ToString)
        Next
        ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    End Sub`

Or is there a simpler way of doing that?

Comment: You can try it. It should work. By calling `ToString()`, you create new items that are inserted in `ListBox2`.

Comment: Question. Lets say i add two hide show buttons to show and hide listbox1, and listbox 2 for button1 and another button to hide listbox3 and 4. However, i have listbox 3 and 4 below listbox 1 and 2. What i want to do is move the listbox3, and 4 items up. How would i do that? Thank you so much in advance if you have any ideas.

Comment: You can group `ListBox1` and `ListBox2` in a Panel (`Panel12`) and `ListBox3` and `ListBox4` in another Panel (`Panel34`). When you click on `Button1`, you hide `Panel1`; when you click on the other button, you hide `Panel34`.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to is to add the item to ListBox2 and then delete from ListBox1

```
Protected Sub AddOneButton0_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddOneButton0.Click
        If (ListBox1.SelectedIndex = -1) Then
            MsgBox("please select an item")
        Else
            ListItem item = ListBox1.SelectedItem
            ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
            ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: now when i click the add button with selected item being "test" it is adding a test2 item twice. not sure why.